# iOS calendar search for events (older than a year)

Tags: ios, calendar

iOS (iphone and iPad) calendar app no longer gives results over a year when I do a search.  On MacOS calendar app shows all matching results regardless of date.

Anyone know how can I get iPhone/iPad calendar app to show ALL matching search results regardless of age?

Data source is iCloud calendar

Comment: '1 year' is an odd value, as it's not an option in the Calendar Sync prefs. Check Settings>Calendar>Sync - what value is set?

Comment: Settings>Calendar>Sync - all events

Comment: OK, then I have no explanation, sorry :\